# "The" with proper names

Tags: nouns, articles

Why is it "The Boston Marathon" and not "Boston Marathon"?
I've read a whole book written solely about articles, and there's not a single word about such example.

Comment: Articles don't have any "why". They are associated with some names and not others, as individual speech habits have decreed, long ago. Thus it's _The University of Michigan_, but another university not far away is _Michigan State University_. There's no single rule; as with all proper names, this has to be learned for each one individually.

Comment: You will find that it's "Boston Marathon". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_Marathon However, in sentences, you will find "the Boston Marathon" because there is a sentence after it. Just like in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Both 'Arsenal' and 'The Arsenal' are used to refer to the London football club. 'Everest' but 'The Matterhorn'. But note that it's 'The FA Cup Final', 'The World Cup', 'The Superbowl', 'The Indianapolis 500' (but 'Indy 500') ....

Comment: It's not really "The Boston Marathon" since you don't see "The Boston Marathon" appear midsentence like that with a capital T at the beginning of "the" unless it starts a sentence. Similar questions have been asked about "the Bible," "the Beatles," etc.

Comment: Include research you have done. Specifically did you search StackExchange for similar questions already answered? 
What did you find?